# AngularJS passing JSON object to directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm getting json file from REST server using factory:

```
.factory('chartData', function($http){
    return {
        get: function() {
            return $http.get('http://').then(function(result) {
                    return result.data;
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Now how can i pass this to directive which i'm using to make chart?
I suppose i would need to use controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises do not work this way.

Try this:

```
.factory('chartData', function($http){
    return {
        get: function() {
            return $http.get('http://');
        }
    }
});
```

and in your directive:

```
chartData.get().then(function(result) {
     $scope.chartData = result.data;
     initChart();
});
```

This video can be helpfull: [angularjs-promises](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-promises)